# Pass type to a function

Tags: ios, swift, generics, alamofire, mapper

This is the code:

```
protocol RESTResource {
    func fullURL() -> NSURL
    func parameters() -> [String: AnyObject]
    func response() -> Mappable.Type
    func keyPath() -> String

    func headers() -> [String: String]?
}

protocol RemoteObjectsTable {

}

extension RemoteObjectsTable {

    func setupRemoteObjectsTable(resource: RESTResource) {        
        request(.GET, resource.fullURL(), parameters: resource.parameters(), headers: resource.headers())
        .responseObject { (response: Response<resource.response(), NSError>) -> Void in

        }
    }
}
```

The signature of the responseObject function (from AlamofireObjectMapper) is:

```
public func responseObject<T: Mappable>(keyPath: String, completionHandler: Response<T, NSError> -> Void) -> Self
```

I'm trying to get a generic class that conforms to the Mappable protocol in the response() function of the RESTResource protocol.
But it gives me an error when trying to do so. It doesn't seem to recognize Response as a valid parameter for Response.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.